# Admob, really bad fillrate

Tags: android, admob, ads

I wonder if Admob has gone really rotten. When I try on my and my friends phones I am very rarly able to get an ad. I know that it works but it seems like Admob never has an ad to show. Yesterday I had a fillrate of 10% and I starting to feel a little bit cheated now.

I know about how to place the ad, the problem is that no ads are delivered. My application have had the ads for several month now so I the "startuptime" shouldn't be an issue eiter.

The only thing that I feel I can do to make a change is to change the keyword-string. It is "drink alcohol wiskey rum soda" now but I have not seen any ads related to those values anyway to I don't think that they are related.

Any thoughts? Should I change ad-engine?

Thanks in advance
Roland

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an Admob support issue, not programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the reasons could be that Admob has a policy where it gives more fill-rate to those people who earn them more money. This means that if you have an app which is doing really well, you will get better fill-rate.

You cannot force Admob to give you better fill-rate. The best way to go if you're using Admob is to create multiple applications, and connect them through House Ads. That ways, even if your app is not getting ads, it is at least promoting your other apps, which leads to overall increase in your application downloads. Moreover, an increase in app downloads also means that you'll get better fill rate in the future !

Of course, you have the option of switching to other ad providers, or using something like AdWhirl which lets you circulate ads.

EDIT: I've realized with time that including just one more advertisement provider and circulating advertisements using AdWhirl could increase your revenue by three to four times!

Comment: i think it's because u have made some violation like false clicks or something

Comment: i got fill rate 0.15% (just install this week), is it normal ?

Comment: Now, what is your suggestion after AdMob mediation?

Comment: Here is my question with current data: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57977839/admob-mediation-lower-fill-rate

Answer (score 3):

Admob fill rate is influenced majorly by click quality. If there are too many errant clicks, Admob throttles fill rate.

See "Best practices" slide in this deck:
http://www.scribd.com/doc/31163718/AdMob-Developer-Day-Developer-Tips-Best-Practices-Aziz-Ruiz

Comment: maybe. then how i can fix it? i have an app with 100% fill rate for like a year. but recently it dropped to 50%. can i fix it by stopping the ads for several days?

Comment: What is the CTR? If it is too high (>2%?) or you know there are too many errant clicks, try reducing such clicks. Stopping ads would not help I guess because stopping would not affect click quality.

Answer (score 2):

I was suffering from terrible fill rate too at about 25%.

I fixed it by going into **Manage Settings > App Settings** and setting the following:

- Automatic Refresh to 12 seconds (formerly at 60).

  - *In the context of my app, the view lifetime is < 30 seconds.  I still sometimes don't see an ad when the View first loads, but I usually see one or two before the 30 second mark.*
- Set Disable Test Mode for all requests
- Set Use Google AdSense to improve fill rate.

This is my first time using AdMob and my approach might not be optimal, but these changes have worked to improve my fill rate.

Comment: Hi, where i can found this setting ? in admob or adsense ?

Answer (score 0):

I would turn off the keywords. In my experience they could severely impact the fill rate. It looks like that there is not enough various ads in Admob system, so that using keywords would work as it should, and with good fillrate.