# Admob Mediation Lower Fill Rate

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, admob

I have developed this game and published this in Play store.
[Drifter.IO](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ubaidussen.drifter)

I have set up AdMob mediation for my earning purpose and integrated other 3 ad network apart from AdMob.
Following image explain this clearly:
[image]

As per you see in the above image, I am getting really low Fill Rate in all ad networks so I am losing many customers request without any advertisements display.

So my question is, what is the solution for this purpose? How can I increase my ad network Fill Rate?

Provide your side suggestion or experience to me so I can apply and test.

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4897344/12065390) on a similar question about fill rate.

Comment: @user601 I have gone through all answers but nothing come with an actual answer and that question is too much older